# PCA() got an unexpected keyword argument 'k'

Tags: pyspark, pca, apache-spark-ml

I am trying t perform pca from a spark application using PySpark API on a python script. I doing This way:

```python
pca = PCA(k=3, inputCol="features", outputCol="pcaFeatures")
PCAmodel = pca.fit(data)
```

when I run those two code line in the pyspark shell it work and return good results, but in an application script, I am getting the type of error:

> PCA() got an unexpected keyword argument 'k'

**PS: In both case I am using Spark 2.2.0**

where is the problem? why it does work in the PySpark shell and not for the application?

Comment: I am using spark 2.2.0

Answer (score 3):

You probably imported from `ml` in one case:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA
```

and `mllib` in the other:

```
from pyspark.mllib.feature import PCA
```

Comment: no, this not my case, for both case I'm using `from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have not also imported `PCA` from `scikit-learn`, *after* you imported it from PySpark in your application script?

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# PySpark syntax with scikit-learn PCA function
pca = PCA(k=3, inputCol="features", outputCol="pcaFeatures") 
# Error:  
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'k'
```

Reversing the order of imports will not produce the error (not shown).

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming your classes:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA as PCAML
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA as PCASK

pca_ml = PCAML(k=3, inputCol="features", outputCol="pcaFeatures")
```

There should be no confusion, then, which one you call.